# how to use url encode for login sessions?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have created a session for login and it gets a token from the session and goes to the same page with user method having a get request and returns a response 200.
This is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib2
import urllib
s=requests.Session()
url = "http://www.example.com/api/2/"
url1= "http://www.example.com/api/2/areas"

values = {
      'username': 'XXXXXXX',
      'password': 'XXXXXXX',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length':'3000'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

And my output is :

```
   response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that may cause the error. What does the server expect?

Comment: This line: `s=requests.Session()` is not actually doing anything, because you are not using requests to fetch the resource.

Comment: First ensure the request works using a tool able to send POST request such as `wget` but you also find firefox plugins (just google firefox rest plugin and choose yours). Then **once you are sure you know what should be sent in the request** control what is actually sent with, for example, `wireshark`. And then if you cannot use Python to send what you want come back here and give a little more background. Alone *it doesn't work* does not give good answers.